# Reduce Google Places API requests

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

While map loads has reduced to $0.5 per 1000, and geocoding can be performed at client side, I can't seem to find how can Places requests be reduced. Furthermore,

*"Note that some services may have a multiplier. For example, Text Search is subject to a 10 times multiplier, causing each Text Search request to count as 10 requests against your quota."*

If my app has the features to suggest hotels, restaurants, etc, doesn't each panning constitute one request?

Comment: What do you mean by "how can Places requests be reduced?" Are you trying to find out how much the Places API costs?

Answer (score 0):

> "...query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day. (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.)"
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

You could add a delay to your input auto suggest. At least then users inputting text will be reduced. This was done on a project I work with, and it cut down requests by a big chunk.

Comment: Thanks. But I am searching if there is any feasible way to reduce the requests, by caching results or other ways.

Comment: @Travis : Can you please explain how do you add delay to input auto suggest ?